# Decoding two different JSON responses in one model class using Codable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

Based on the requirement I got two different kinds of response from api. That is

```
{
  "shopname":"xxx",
  "quantity":4,
  "id":1,
  "price":200.00,
}
```

another response

```
{
  "storename":"xxx",
  "qty":4,
  "id":1,
  "amount":200.00,
}
```

Here both json values are decoding in same model class. Kindly help me to resolve this concern.

is it is possible to set value in single variable like **qty** and **quantity** both are stored in same variable based on key param availability

Comment: add both json resposne in one model class  like josn {
  "shopname":"xxx",
  "quantity":4,
  "id":1,
  "price":200.00,
  "storename":"xxx",
  "qty":4,
  "amount":200.00,
} and then create model class

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach that lets you have only one property in your code, instead of two Optionals:

Define a struct that contains all the properties you need, with the names that you'd like to use in your code. Then, define two `CodingKey` enums that map those properties to the two different JSON formats and implement a custom initializer:

```
let json1 = """
{
    "shopname":"xxx",
    "quantity":4,
    "id":1,
    "price":200.00,
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let json2 = """
{
    "storename":"xxx",
    "qty":4,
    "id":1,
    "amount":200.00,
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct DecodingError: Error {}

struct Model: Decodable {
    let storename: String
    let quantity: Int
    let id: Int
    let price: Double

    enum CodingKeys1: String, CodingKey {
        case storename = "shopname"
        case quantity
        case id
        case price
    }

    enum CodingKeys2: String, CodingKey {
        case storename
        case quantity = "qty"
        case id
        case price = "amount"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container1 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys1.self)
        let container2 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys2.self)

        if let storename = try container1.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys1.storename) {
            self.storename = storename
            self.quantity = try container1.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys1.quantity)
            self.id = try container1.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys1.id)
            self.price = try container1.decode(Double.self, forKey: CodingKeys1.price)
        } else if let storename = try container2.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys2.storename) {
            self.storename = storename
            self.quantity = try container2.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys2.quantity)
            self.id = try container2.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys2.id)
            self.price = try container2.decode(Double.self, forKey: CodingKeys2.price)
        } else {
            throw DecodingError()
        }
    }
}


do {
    let j1 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: json1)
    print(j1)
    let j2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: json2)
    print(j2)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Data` as your model name. It's already a foundation type.

Comment: True, that can be confusing. Updated my answer.

Comment: `let json1 = """
{
    "shopname":"xxx",
    "quantity":4,
    "id":1,
    "price":200.00,
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let json2 = """
{
    "storename":"xxx",
    "qty":4,
    "id":1,
    "amount":200.00,
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!`

Here need to pass my json response??
Kindly share some helpful url to know more about my concern.

Comment: That's just an example so you can try the code e.g. in a playground. In your code, you would use your JSON response data in place of my `json1` or `json2`

Comment: @Gereon Thanks You

Comment: @PartheeVs but why don't you mark it as the answer? I mean green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

**Handling different key names in single model**

Below are two sample json(dictionaries) that have some common keys (one, two) and a few different keys (which serve the same purpose of error).

Sample json:

```
let error_json:[String: Any] = [
    "error_code": 404,                  //different
    "error_message": "file not found",  //different
    "one":1, //common
    "two":2  //common
]
let failure_json:[String: Any] = [
    "failure_code": 404,                 //different
    "failure_message": "file not found", //different
    "one":1, //common
    "two":2  //common
]
```

CommonModel

```
struct CommonModel : Decodable {
    var code: Int?
    var message: String?
    var one:Int  //common
    var two:Int? //common
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{ //common
        case one, two
    }
    private enum Error_CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case  code = "error_code", message = "error_message"
    }
    private enum Failure_CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case  code = "failure_code", message = "failure_message"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let commonValues =  try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let errors = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Error_CodingKeys.self)
        let failures = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Failure_CodingKeys.self)
        
        ///common
        self.one = try commonValues.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .one)!
        self.two = try commonValues.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .two)
        /// different
        if errors.allKeys.count > 0{
            self.code = try errors.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .code)
            self.message = try errors.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
        }
        if failures.allKeys.count > 0{
            self.code = try failures.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .code)
            self.message = try failures.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
        }
    }
}
```

Below extension will help you to convert your dictionary to data.

```
public extension Decodable {
    init(from: Any) throws {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: from, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        self = try decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Testing

```
public func Test_codeble(){
    do {
         let err_obj = try CommonModel(from: error_json)
         print(err_obj)
         let failed_obj = try CommonModel(from: failure_json)
         print(failed_obj)
        
    }catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like

```
struct modelClass : Codable {

    let amount : Float?
    let id : Int?
    let price : Float?
    let qty : Int?
    let quantity : Int?
    let shopname : String?
    let storename : String?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amount = "amount"
        case id = "id"
        case price = "price"
        case qty = "qty"
        case quantity = "quantity"
        case shopname = "shopname"
        case storename = "storename"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        amount = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .amount)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        price = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .price)
        qty = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .qty)
        quantity = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .quantity)
        shopname = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .shopname)
        storename = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .storename)
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks @vikash.. is it is possible to set value in single variable. like `qty` and `quantity` both are stored in same variable based on availability